# How to add Javadoc for Servlet API in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, javadoc

I've a dynamic web app in Eclipse that is using Tomcat as runtime environment.

I cannot add Javadoc path Tomcat Servlet API: as appears, the edit button is always disabled!

[alt text http://filaty.com/i/1005/80306/tom.JPG](http://filaty.com/i/1005/80306/tom.JPG)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Package Explorer of your project go to *Java Resources > Libraries*. Rightclick `servlet-api.jar`, choose *Properties* and specify the source location there (the `apache-tomcat-x.x.x-src.zip` file).

Another way is to just open any Servlet API class using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click on any import/declaration in existing code and then click the *Attach Source...* button and specify it there.

Comment: Thanks really helpfull!

Comment: You can download the source zip file from this [address](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/tomcat-servlet/tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.27-sources.jar.zip). Additionally I had to extract this zip file to get the jar file and attach as java source as attaching the zip file directly did not work for me.

Answer (score 6):

You could download the source jars for the servlet api from [Maven](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/) and either build your own javadoc jar or just use the sources.

Answer (score 3):

**First**, download the "Full documentation" from the tomcat website. As Example for tomcat 8.5.23:
https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi

[image: tomcat full documantation]

You'll get a tar.gz file which you have to unzip since eclipse only can read folders or zip / jar.

**Second**, set in your Java Build Path the Javadoc location for library Tomcat and "servlet-api.jar". Point to the folder "(...)\tomcat-8.5-doc\servletapi":

[image: eclipse tomcat servlet-api.jar]

And now eclipse will show you the correct Javadoc:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been continuously trying to attach the sources for `javax.` libs in a proper way with no result, until I found that in some cases by some reason *Eclipse* is messing up the relationship between *.jar* and its classes. E.g. when I clicked upon *Attach Source...* for the `HttpServlet.class` the given option to provide sources for my `gwt-user.jar` lib confused me a little bit.

Hence one may try to play with the precedence of his libs at *Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export* to put your kit over the rest (e.g. put `Apache Tomcat v7.0` library higher then `GWT SDK`). Also at the *Libraries* tab provide the proper sources archive for `servlet-api.jar` like <kbd>apache-tomcat-7.0.22-src.zip</kbd>. Magically the problem is solved after all.

Answer (score 0):

In Package Explorer of your project go to Java Resources > Libraries. Rightclick servlet-api.jar, choose Properties and specify the source location there (the apache-tomcat-x.x.x-src.zip file).

or

In Package Explorer of your project go to Java Resources > Libraries. Rightclick servlet-api.jar, choose Properties and specify the source location there (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/). This will give a direct link to the api online.