# How to get eclipse+maven to find and use servlet api source code or javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Recently, I downloaded the latest elcipse with everything in it, and added the sonatype maven plugin.

We setup a number of servlet projects using the mavel eclipse plugin web archtypes to generate the poms etc.

It adds:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
```

However, it doesnt include the source or javadocs, so developing with this is a lot of groping in the dark and constant hunting of javadoc web pages.

I have scoured the maven website http://maven.apache.org/,  but cant find how to get it to include the source or javadoc as well as the actual dependant jar.

I saw this article, but it doesnt have a solution:

[How to add Javadoc for Servlet API in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869485/how-to-add-javadoc-for-servlet-api-in-eclipse)

And this tip: http://tedwise.com/2010/01/27/maven-micro-tip-get-sources-and-javadocs/ but last time I used a mvn command outside of eclilpse, it destroyed the whole eclipse environment and I spent 2 days rebuiling it from scratch (now I know not to do that).

Or do i have to manually add a jar of the source which exactly matches the java jar to ecilpse as source in the java build path?  (i.e. not use maven).  I found a copy of the source here: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.4/

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding classifier inside dependency tags:

```
<classifier>sources</classifier>
```

OR changing Eclipse preferences:

```
Eclipse > (Toolbar) > Window > Preferences > Maven:
Download Artifact JavaDoc
Download Artifact Source
```

(And then touch your pom file in Eclipse to make new Maven build.)

Edit: `source` in classifier tag corrected to `sources`

Comment: Good tips.  I just tried adding the source classifier, but it then gives an error in the pom file: `Missing artifact javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:source:2.4:provided`

Comment: Also, when tried the second optoin, ticking "download artifact source", I always get: `An internal error occurred during: "Updating status for Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost...".
java.lang.NullPointerException`  It doesnt download the source - it didnt work for me.

Comment: @wingnut Use sources instead of source in classifier. I have corrected my answer too.

Comment: Adding <classifier>sources</classifier> thusly:

Comment: Adding <classifier>sources</classifier> into the servlet dependency has broken the project in eclipse: it now cant resolve any of the javax.servlet.xxx (even after clean/rebuild/restart/update project configration etc) However, maven still builds the war ok. Eclipse still has the servlet jar in its build path.  When I remove the classifer, eclipse is happy again (but no sources).