# Cannot open declaration on Eclipse(Source not found) - HttpServlet.class

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, javadoc

I am Trying to open declaration on Eclipse Neon.1(Mac OS X).

open other classes such as PrintWriter.class is working fine but when I open httpServlet.class's declaration. Source can't be found.

below is screenshots of what I am struggling now. I've searched for this problem but I couldn't find a solution. please help.

[image]

[image: source not found]

[image: Jar files imported]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869485/how-to-add-javadoc-for-servlet-api-in-eclipse

comments and this linked question solved my Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpServlet.class` is part of the Servlet API which you probably imported into your project. Whereas `PrintWriter.class` is part of the Java SDK which by default is shipped with the sources as well.

In order to watch the source of `HttpServlet.class` you need to import the sources jar as well.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am using tomcat v7.0 as a server and already imported it's JAR files to project libraries. and done building path.

Comment: @KHW1031 The code you have is compiled code. Source jars are not guaranteed to be included in the same jar. It is normal that you have separate source jars and these must be included as well to view source.

Answer (score 0):

You're using tomcat v7 right?
Go to https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi
Navigate to bottom of page
you'll find "Source Code Distributions". Download the zip version, not tar version. 
Open eclipse, Attach this file as source when you open declaration of the HttpServletRequest.