# Adding source code to all jars of Tomcat9 Targeted Runtime in Eclipse so that F3 opens source code

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

In a *Dynamic Web Project* in Eclipse I have a Tomcat9 attached as a Targeted Runtime (I downloaded binary distribution from [official site](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi)

But if I press F3 on any class (say, `SimpleTagSupport` class) no source code appears because it is not attached.

How to add source code?

I understand I can download source code distribution

[image]

And I understand how to add source code:

[image]

In my case ( SimpleTagSupport ) it is

[image]

But can I somehow **attach source code to *all* jars in Tomcat Targeted Runtime?** It is a tiresom work to manually find source and attach it to each jar!

Besides I cannot find needed source-folders for all respective jars, b/c source distributions looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also it turns out ot be that `java/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext` folder does not contain any valid source files, but what shall add as source to servlet-api.jar or for javax.servlet.jsp.tagext package (for SimpleTagSupport class)...

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that for every .jar (for example for servlet-api.jar) you specify entire src.zip file (Eclipse will figure out the needed part itself)

Solution is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869485/how-to-add-javadoc-for-servlet-api-in-eclipse)

[image]

[image]

Use: https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/

If we add *source files* then besides opening source by F3 it also enables tooltip (javadoc) help (taken from javadocs inside source files) on hover (or F2), but Shift+F2 would not work.

To enable Shift+F2 we need to *explicitly attach Javadoc* (attach source is not enough for Shift+F2).

Download Tomcat's *Full Documentation* (not source!!!), unarchive it and then use **file:///** notation:

> file:/K:/SERVERS/apache-tomcat-9.0.16-fulldocs/tomcat-9.0-doc/servletapi

[image]

Now Shift+F2 is enabled!